Why is electric potential due to a positive point charge positive?
I am confused about the sign of electrical potential due to a positive  point charge since I started electrostatics. It is always giving me a negative sign when  I try to prove it. I would be thankful if you can help me out. Please see images for reference.



Walter Lewin explains right in the beginning of the lecture how to calculate the electric potential of a point particle. I suggest that you watch the video and find your mistake. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpVxj3XrLgk

@physicopath Oh i got it, what i was doing wrong was that i was taking the dr vector to be opposite to electric field(in reference of small q) but it is actually from the reference of charge Q not small q

Please use MathJax to type mathematical expressions.

This has been asked many times. Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17938/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436432/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357819/174766

we need to see what you did to (dis)prove it. Otherwise, the answer is: it's positive.
